# I can't get rid of &nbsp in my output php

Tags: php, html

Here's my html form

```
<form method="post" action="parseme.php">
  <textarea name="dadata" cols="40" rows="5" name="myname">
  </textarea>
  <INPUT TYPE="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Here's the php

```
<?php
  $da_data = (string)$_POST['dadata'];
  $da_data = mb_convert_encoding($da_data, "UTF-8");
  $da_data = str_replace("&nbsp", " ",$da_data);
  $da_data = str_replace("\n", " ", $da_data);
  $da_data = str_replace("\r", " ", $da_data);
  $da_data = str_replace("&nbsp;","", $da_data);
  $da_data = str_replace('<', "[", $da_data);
  $da_data = str_replace(">", "]", $da_data);
  $da_data = str_replace("\"", "", $da_data);
  $da_data = str_replace('\'', "", $da_data);   
  $da_data = str_replace(' ',"", $da_data);
  $da_data = explode(",", $da_data);

  foreach ($da_data as $email) {
    echo $email . "<br>";
  }
?>
```

The data I enter keeps on spitting out &nbsp in front of every line. I've been working at this for a couple of hours now. What am I missing?!?

Comment: Provide the exact text

Comment: https://gist.github.com/yangkennyk/9656496

Comment: You have 2 `name` attributes by the way, and if you have `</textarea>` on a new line there will be initial whitespace in your input.

Comment: @Kenny: I don't see any `&nbsp;` there

Comment: Skip all that junk and juset use [htmlspecialchars](http://us1.php.net/htmlspecialchars). Or, if you send the email as plain text then you don't need to worry about XSS or HTML code, escaping, etc.

Comment: @zerkms in the gist I posted? I'm inspecting with chrome and it's showing &nbsp in front of both lines. =\

Comment: @Kenny You're looking at github's source code for that HTML page, that's why. Your gist is `txt` so we would see any HTML entities, code, etc..

Comment: @WesleyMurch I'm trying to create a text parser that creates a csv with email/first/last so there are a bunch of junk entities that I wanted to get rid of.

Comment: @Kenny: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yangkennyk/9656496/raw/774fabfa1f4e7c8ea99179b5d1dcc68be2fdefa3/gistfile1.txt --- here is the raw text you posted and **THERE IS NO** `&nbsp;` there

Comment: Unless there is more code, there shouldn't be any HTML or HTML entities unless the user types them. Please amend your post with the output of `exit(var_dump($_POST['dadata']))`.

Comment: @zerkms this is what I'm seeing: http://i.imgur.com/24s92JT.png

Comment: @WesleyMurch the user isn't going to be typing text in. I'm creating this for someone to paste in a gmail CC list. so it looks like it comes with special characters in the paste.

Comment: @Kenny: raw view outputs raw data - you **DO NOT** need to use chrome dev tools which presumably adds something to that. If you still don't believe me - take curl or wget and download your file using the given linke: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yangkennyk/9656496/raw/774fabfa1f4e7c8ea99179b5d1dcc68be2fdefa3/gistfile1.txt.

Comment: @zerkms chrome still renders a noticeable white space in front for me though. so is that normal?

Comment: @Kenny: there is a space character indeed. But there is no an `&nbsp;` there. So, as soon as **there is no** `&nbs;p` - what your question is about?

Comment: @zerkms how do I get rid of the space then? I've tried 
    $da_data = str_replace(" ","", $da_data); with no success. and the trim() function doesn't work either.

Comment: @zerkms I added a doctype and now the spaces are rendering as black squares with question marks in them. http://i.imgur.com/iPfiX8C.png

Comment: Oh I see, it's actually a `0xC2` character there followed by a `0xA0` http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c2a0/index.htm

Comment: @zerkms any idea on how I can strip it?

Comment: @Kenny: can you provide a criteria for stripping characters? What's wrong with this unicode char?

Comment: @zerkms to be honest it's just annoying that I can't figure out how to strip it. I plan on outputting the data as a csv and would rather not have it there.

Comment: @zerkms I found the answer. thanks for sticking with me and helping! $da_data = mb_convert_encoding( $da_data, "HTML-ENTITIES","UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
<form method="post" action="parseme.php">
<textarea name="dadata" cols="40" rows="5" name="myname"></textarea>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Every space is being recognized when it comes to textarea, also try:

```
  <?php
  $da_data = trim($_POST['dadata']);
```

Comment: isn't that the same as what I have?? I tried trim but it didn't work.

I added a doc type and now the spaces are rendered as question mark

http://i.imgur.com/iPfiX8C.png

Comment: i also encountered this, having white spaces in the first data i retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but adding this to my php removes the white space.

```
$da_data = mb_convert_encoding( $da_data, "HTML-ENTITIES","UTF-8");
```